# Can I send several events on action in flux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to show loader when authentication happens. I've got `sendAuthCredentials` action. On this action I want to do several actions:

1. Show Loader
2. Send auth request to server
3. Handle response and inform `UserStore` is user authenticated or not
4. Hide Loader.

I've got `Loader` react component, `LoaderStore` and `LoaderAction` for working with component.

So my `sendAuthCredentials` method looks like:

```js
UserActions = {
/**
 * @param {string} username
 * @param {string} password
 */
  sendAuthCredentials: function(username, password) {
    return Q.all(
      [
        LoaderActions.showLoader(),
        authenticateUser(username, password)
          .then(function( data ) {
            if( data ) {
              AppDispatcher.handleViewAction({
                type: ActionTypes.USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
                data: data
              });
              return Q( "succcess" );
            } else {
              AppDispatcher.handleViewAction({
                type: ActionTypes.USER_LOGIN_FAIL
              });
              return Q( "failed" );
            }
          })
      ]
    ).then(LoaderActions.hideLoader);
  }
};
```

It's works but I'm not sure Is it right way to use Actions in Flux.

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is fine as it is, but as you mention you are not utilizing the potential in Flux. If you utilize Flux you do not need to use promises to keep track of your async calls. The numbered list of actions you mention is just a regular Flux data flow.

With Flux you would have a UserStore where you could store if this user was authenticated or not (plus other data you would want to store about a user). You could then just prompt the loader until you got an event dispatched from the UserStore telling you that the user is authenticated or not.

```
var authenticateUser = function(username) {
  <getRequestToAuthentticationResource>
  .then(function(data){
    <storeDataInUserStore>
    emitAuthenticated();
  })
}
var UserStore = _.extend({}, EventEmitter.prototype, {
  dispatcherIndex: AppDispatcher.register(function(payload) {
  var action = payload;
  switch (action.actionType) {
    case UserConstants.AUTHENTICATE:
      authenticateUser(action.username);
      break;
  }
}
```

Under is an example of how your app would listen and handle the event. Just to clarify, this is a very simple component. You could check the authCode in a better way than with an if-else.

```
 var YourApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
       authCode: "loading"
    }
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    UserStore.addAuthListener(this._onChange);
  },       

  _onChange: function() {
    setState({
       authCode: UserStore.getAuthCode() //Sucess or fail
    });
  }

  render: function() {
    if(this.state.authCode === "loading"){
      return <load information>
    } else if(this.state.authCode === "success") {
      return <success information>
    } else {
      return <fail>
    }
 }
```

Then your React-component would just have to see what data it would get and show either the user information, error or the loader.

Just remember you need an addAuthListener in your store and an emitAuthenticated to make this work.

Best practice is to do the getRequest where you dispatch the actions, and when that returns you notify the store. However, as seen in the example, you can do it in the store as well.

Comment: Thank you for your response. As I understand you send async requests in store. Am I right? But as I understand It's also ok to send requests on actions. Also I want to have a Loader component that I'll use several times. user authentication, comment posting etc. So I initialize in action 2 data flows: for updating `UserStore` and for updating `LoaderStore`. So I'm not sure can I do like so or not.

Comment: You can send async request in store yeah, but I think its generally a little prettier to do it in the ActionDispatcher. 
If you want a reusable loader component I think you need some different cases depending on which scope you are in, or if you can think of an event that can be triggered and tell every loader to finish. 
You can do it as you propose, but I am uncertain that you need an own LoaderStore. What information do you have to store outside the Loader-component? Remember to use properties and states to your advantage.

Comment: I have a status of loader(display or not) in LoaderStore. I use state to control loader component. so I've got actions: showLoader and hideLoader. LoaderStore emits event if status of loader changing. Loader component listens events and shows loader or not. This component looks good, but I should send showLoader/hideLoader actions from another actions. And I'm not sure is it right or not.

Comment: There is no definite right or wrong here, there seldom is. I would, if I understand your approach correctly, connect each loader to the component it belongs to. This doesnt mean that you have  to make several loader components, just declare them in each component where it is used. When you auth a user, do an action of some sort. This means that you can let the parent component determine if the loader is done or not. This would probably relieve you of the showLoader/hideLoader-action.